# Add a delete photo option PHP

Tags: php, session, gallery

So basically I have a PHP script that takes all the images from the user's individual folder in the directory and displays them on his/her gallery page. Now I want to add a delete function but im lost as to how to do it.
Any help would be great!

```
<?php
$userid = $_GET['UID'];

$img_path = "./$userid";

chdir($img_path);

$images = glob('*.{jpg, jpeg, png, gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($images as $image){
    if (file_exists("./thumbs/$img_path/{image}")){
        echo "<a href='$img_path/{$image}' rel='lightbox'><img src='./thumbs/$img_path/{$image}' alt=\"{$image}\" /></a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='$img_path/{$image}' rel='lightbox'><img src='./$img_path/{$image}' width='200' height='150'   alt=\"{$image}\" /></a>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: try `unlink($filename)` function for delete

Comment: If I go to the URL of your script and add ?UID=id_of_some_user_i_know_has_privilaged_access to the URL, you're going to have a rather bad day.

Comment: And where abouts would I place that? would it need its one foreach?

Comment: @TomDuffy You're trusting user input. NEVER trust user input.  I could put anything I want into UID with virtually no effort at all.  You have to make sure the data you're working with is valid before you try actually using it.

Comment: I was assuming that he's just starting out with PHP and learning the basics... not worrying about security yet, but for future reference, you should pick up this book and read thoroughly before making a site for someone else: http://phpsecurity.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an anchor tag in the gallery with the file name as identification attribute. for example.

```
<?php
$userid = $_GET['UID'];

$img_path = "./$userid";

chdir($img_path);

$images = glob('*.{jpg, jpeg, png, gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($images as $image){
    if (file_exists("./thumbs/$img_path/{image}")){
        echo "<a href='$img_path/{$image}' rel='lightbox'><img src='./thumbs/$img_path/{$image}' alt=\"{$image}\" /></a>";
        //add this line
        echo "<a href='$img_path/{$image}?delete=$image' rel='lightbox'>Delete</a>";    
    } else {
        echo "<a href='$img_path/{$image}' rel='lightbox'><img src='./$img_path/{$image}' width='200' height='150'   alt=\"{$image}\" /></a>";
    }
}

//Updated and fixed the error, there was missing closing bracket here.
if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $image = $_GET['delete'];
    unlink('./thumbs/'.$img_path.'/'.$image);
}
```

Comment: Give me a minute, im getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on if(isset($_GET['delete']) { with your code, so i have to just figure out whats wrong with it

Comment: I have a parse error with your //condition to delete the file

Comment: probably the error signifies missing colon or closing bracket. can you show me the exact error ?

Comment: got it there is a missing closing bracket in the if condition ill update the code.

Comment: Yep its running now, but no delete option appears? I see you have echo'd one?

Comment: check with my answer properly, you need to add a line of code in your foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.delete.php) function of php:

```
<?php
unlink('./' . $img_path . '/' . $image);
unlink('./thumbs/' . $img_path . '/' . $image);
?>
```

Comment: And I then add a delete button in HTML under the image which calls this function?

Comment: Yes, like what answeres Ibrahim under my post . That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

create a delete button inside anchor tags that directs the page to a delete script, passing in the URL of the image, or the id of the image as a parameter...

```
<a href="http://example.com/delete.php?type=image&id=1">Delete this image</a>
```

Inside that script, you might have to change the permissions of the file/directory: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

before deleting (unlinking) the file: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php.

Then send the user back to the original page with a call to header(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I think I can mannage all this, just one small question with your delete image link, how do i send the image url dynamically to that line?

Comment: it looks like you'd just use the same link you're dumping inside the <img /> tag: `<a href="http://example.com/delete.php?type=image&url=' . $img_path/{$image} . '">Delete this image</a>`